# ANTV npm install fails

Tags: reactjs, antd, antv

Installing ANTV fails without --legacy-peer-deps option.

NPM install fails with:
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @ant-design/charts@1.4.2
npm ERR! Found: @ant-design/icons@5.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@ant-design/icons
npm ERR!   @ant-design/icons@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   @ant-design/icons@"^5.0.0" from antd@5.1.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/antd
npm ERR!     antd@"^5.1.6" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer antd@">=4.4.2 || >=5.0.0-beta.0" from @antv/x6-react-components@1.1.20

Package.json looks like:
"engines": {
"node": "18.x",
"npm": "8.x"
},
"dependencies": {
"@ant-design/charts": "^1.4.2",
"@ant-design/icons": "^5.0.1",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"antd": "^5.1.6",
"classnames": "^2.3.2",
"prop-types": "^15.8.1",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"serve": "^14.2.0",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},

Comment: Please format the error message and package.json in code blocks to make them easier to read. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. There is currently a conflict between the @ant-design/charts and @ant-design/icons packages. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-charts/issues/1689).

I fixed my issue by selectively installing the needed antd charts. For example instead of installing @ant-design/charts, I installed [@ant-design/plots](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ant-design/plots).

Comment: Thanks @joshi - I've had a look at the thread you pointed. I tried the "overrides" method listed but it wasn't that good and did fall back to the "npm i @ant-design/plots" you suggested and which works fine